# app.directive Google Map is not working after hosting

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, google-maps

I am working with MVC 5 Web application with angularjs . There is a Google Map.

In my Angular view, I using the directive in `app.js` for google map.

Please see my below code.

**app.js**

```
myApp.directive('googlemap', function ($compile) {
return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var map;

        this.registerMap = function (myMap) {
            var center = myMap.getCenter(),
              latitude = center.lat(),
              longitude = center.lng();
            //zoom = center.zoom();

            map = myMap;
            $scope.latitude = latitude;
            $scope.longitude = longitude;
            $scope.zoom = map.getZoom();
        };

        $scope.$watch('latitude + longitude', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                var center = map.getCenter(),
                  latitude = center.lat(),
                  longitude = center.lng();
                if ($scope.latitude !== latitude || $scope.longitude !== longitude)
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude));
            }
        });
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var mapOptions,
          latitude = attrs.latitude,
          longitude = attrs.longitude,
          //controlTemplate,
          //controlElem,
          map;

        // parsing latLong or setting default location
        latitude = latitude && parseFloat(latitude, 10) || 43.074688;
        longitude = longitude && parseFloat(longitude, 10) || -89.384294;

        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);

        ctrl.registerMap(map);

        function centerChangedCallback(scope, map) {
            return function () {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                scope.latitude = center.lat();
                scope.longitude = center.lng();
                scope.zoom = map.getZoom();
                if (!scope.$$phase) scope.$apply();
            };
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', centerChangedCallback(scope, map));
    }
};
});
```

**Html**

```
<div style="height:400px;" googlemap latitude="43.074688" longitude="-89.384294"></div>
```

It's works fine in the local host. But when i host this page on webserver,

An error shows in the Google Chrome console:

[image]

I found a difference in `view-source:` of both pages (local host and hosted 
page). The script reference are minimal in the local host and hosted page.

Would you please suggest any advice for this problem?

Comment: are you minifying your javasctipt files?

Comment: No sir, i can't do anything like that

Comment: I asked you..are you minifying javasctipt using bunding on server side?

Comment: Thak you for your valuable reply. Yes i am using this @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myApp") for refer all script. But it's only works in local not after hosting. I call my app.js directly in _Layout.cshtml page. Now it's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I'm pretty sure the problem is loading your scripts,cross check your location of scripts in the host.

Comment: Actually all script references are renderd in local webpage. I am calling bundled script script in my _Layout.cshtml page. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myApp") (It's include app.js).  Now i add reference this app.js directly in _Layout.cshtml page. Now it's worked.